# Specific TrueCrypt action

Tags: truecrypt

I never used TrueCrypt but I thinking about use it to protect my data.

I have specific action on my mind:

When I close my windows 7 specific partition will be crypt, that nobody who steal my laptop can not take my data easly.

And when I log in my system this partition decrypt all data? That it works?

I not sure that it works like that or all the time my files was crypt and only when I want to use it it will be decrypt on fly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work as you understand it.

Search for the title "*Can a volume be automatically mounted whenever I log on to Windows?*" in the [TrueCrypt FAQ](http://www.truecrypt.org/faq).